# Firebase with Google ( ONLY Login )

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to do a **authentication** with firebase that **only allows login to previously created users** and I want to do it using google. Firebase provides the Google Sign-in but it creates the user if it doesn't exist.

There is a way to modify the code to allow only Login registered users ? If not, can you advice me to create a similar login ?

**Login.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private SignInButton signInButton;

    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.entrar);

        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            }
        });


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    goMainScreen();
                }
            }
        };

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(result.getSignInAccount());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO S'HA POGUT CONNECTAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(signInAccount.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO S'HA POGUT AUTENTIFICAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void goMainScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That log-in *making user if they doesn't exists* functionality is provided by **Google** not **Firebase**

Comment: So if you want google sign-in, then, you can't modify that anyway!

Comment: I'm sorry to disapoint you. Firebase is from Google and it allows you the auth by google. But it sign-in the user if it doesn't exist, I only want to grant acces to previously created users. @HarshitSeksaria

Comment: you can do that first check in firebase if the user is exist or not. if exist then follow the steps of google login, in that case new user will not be created. And second scenario, do login with Google, then you will get the google result, extract email id from it. and check if the user is exists.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava that's nice! I'll try it, post it and i'll mark as best answer :)

Comment: down voter, nothing wrong with this question..

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes! I'll post it when i have time. Thanks to make me remember!